# Повторяющий html при обработке данных

Tags: php, javascript, html

Вот, есть такой javascript код:

```
  function updateChat(){
    $.ajax({
      url : "http://localhost/kiosl/rooms/default/protected/models/chat-server.php",
      type : "get",
      data : "last_displayed_chat_id="+$('#last_displayed_chat_id').val(),
      dataType : "json",
      success : function(response , status , http){
        $.each(response, function(index,item){
      document.getElementById("kiosl_chat_box").innerHTML += "<li class='friend'>  <div class='friend-msg-wrap'>  <img class='user-img img-circle block pull-left'  src='../dist/img/user.png' alt='user'/>  <div class='msg pull-left'>  <p>" + item.user_comment +"</p>  <div class='msg-per-detail text-right'>  <span class='msg-time txt-grey'>" + item.user_name + "</span>  </div>  </div>  <div class='clearfix'></div>  </div>  </li>";
        });
      },
      error : function(http, status, error){
        alert('Some Error occured : '+error);
      }
    });
  }
 updateChat();

  setInterval(updateChat, 1000);
```

И вот в чём проблема: каждый раз в ***kiosl_chat_box*** за 1 сек. добавляется html код:

`<li> Бла Бла бла </li>`

Вопрос: как сделать что бы повторяющийся код не добавлялся.

P.S. Мой "опыт" javascript уже поделен на 0.

Comment: Что-то не пойму, в чём у вас проблема. Вы же сами запустили команду на вызов функции `updateChat()` ежесекундно.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin , проблема в том, что в исходном скрипте, после "success" было это:


     $.each(response, function(index,item){
    $('#chat_box').val($('#chat_box').val() + item.user_name + '  : ' + item.user_comment + '\n');
    $('#last_displayed_chat_id').val(item.chat_id);

И такой проблемки не было. Но там данные отправлялись в textarea. А мне нужно что бы они отправлялись в div, для дизайна. Одним словом: я делаю чат, и если у вас есть хороший скрипт real-time чата(без фреймворков), то киньте плиз

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что функция `.val()` вызывает замену всего контента в textarea. То есть, равняется оператору `=`. В текущем же коде вы используете оператор `+=`, то есть оператор присвоения, который добавляет контент на страницу к уже существующему контенту. Проще говоря, добавляет контент. Решить эту задачу вы можете сделав так, чтобы PHP отдавал вам только новые сообщения, а не все сразу. Честно говоря, PHP и не очень-то годится для решения такой задачи. Вам нужно гуглить в сторону long-poll запросов и сокетов, либо же переходить на NodeJS.